# Letter "y" comes after "i" when sorting alphabetically

Tags: r, locale, alphabetical-sort

When using function `sort(x)`, where `x` is a character, the letter "y" jumps into the middle, right after letter "i":

```
> letters
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t"
[21] "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

> sort(letters)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "y" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
[21] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "z"
```

The reason may be that I am located in Lithuania, and this is "lithuanian-like" sorting of letters, but I need normal sorting. How do I change the sorting method back to normal inside R code?

I'm using R 2.15.2 on Win7.

Comment: It will be your locale settings which R will get from Windows. Either change your Windows settings or use `Sys.setlocale` in R.

Comment: Try this:  `Sys.setlocale(category="LC_COLLATE", "C"); sort(letters)`

Comment: This problem is described on the `?Comparison` help page.

Comment: Nitpick w.r.t. `normal sorting`: Thinking of English as "normal" is exactly what leads to tons of globalization bugs...

Comment: @Heinzi: I wish i could upvote you more than once.

Comment: @Heinzi Your response is worthy of an entry in the R `fortunes` package.

Comment: @Heinzi that being said the sorting that is referred to here is the modern Latin alphabetical order. It so happens to be the same in English.

Comment: There ought to be a severe punishment for language designers who make the default version of a function location dependent. The worst part is that it is the people they supposedly try to help, those who use a foreign language, that end up with "exclusive" bugs.

Comment: @eBusiness It is *clearly* documented behaviour in `?sort` if the OP or anyone else so afflicted wanted to read it. The punishment for not reading the docs if far worse than the one for making something locale-dependent.

Comment: Does your code handle normal English words like café, naïve, and façade?

Comment: This is the same for Latvian locale (`Latvian_Latvia.1257`), however there is not letter `y` in Latvian alphabet.

Answer (score 39):

You need to change the locale that R is running in. Either do that for your entire Windows install (which seems suboptimal) or within the R sessions via:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
```

You can use any other valid locale string in place of `"C"` there, but that should get you back to the sort order for `letters` you want.

Read `?locales` for more.

I suppose it is worth noting the sister function `Sys.getlocale()`, which queries the current setting of a locale parameter. Hence you could do

```
(locCol <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE"))
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "lt_LT")
sort(letters)
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", locCol)
sort(letters)
Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")

## giving:
> (locCol <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE"))
[1] "en_GB.UTF-8"
> Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "lt_LT")
[1] "lt_LT"
> sort(letters)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "y" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n"
[16] "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "z"
> Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", locCol)
[1] "en_GB.UTF-8"
> sort(letters)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"
[16] "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
> Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
[1] "en_GB.UTF-8"
```

which of course is what @Hadley's Answer shows `with_collate()` doing somewhat more succinctly once you have **devtools** installed.

Comment: Do you happen to know where one can find the list of available locales (e.g. `"lt_LT"` for Lithuanian, etc.)?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/ lists the ICU names, which are seem to mostly work (only the "xx_YY" form, not the "xx" form) for R on mac (and I assume linux).  Unfortunately it's system specific, and Windows is completely different.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien windows locales at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx (courtesy of JJ Allaire)

Answer (score 34):

If you want to do this temporarily, `devtools` provides the `with_collate` function:

```
library(devtools)
with_collate("C", sort(letters))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
# [20] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
with_collate("lt_LT", sort(letters))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "y" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r"
# [20] "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "z"
```